# Page access based on user type in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

Suppose i have four pages and two user types. After logged in, user one can access all the four pages but for second user we are restricting to access only 2 pages. How can we achieve this in angular 2..?

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular2/1208/routing-3-0-0#t=201701261626364902546

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a guard. Let's take this example:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot} from '@angular/router';
import {UserService} from '../auth';

@Injectable()
export class RoleGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private userService:UserService, private router:Router) {
  }

  canActivate(next:ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state:RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (this.userService.hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
      return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['some-other-route']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Then you add it to your routing:

```
    path: 'pathToAdminRoute',
    component: SomeComponent,
    canActivate: [RoleGuard]
```

What it does is make that particular route only accessible by a user with a specific role (in this case - a user with a role of `"ROLE_ADMIN"`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular2 `guards` (*viz.* `CanActivate`, `CanActivateChild`, `CanDeactivate` & `CanLoad`) to protect/control access to various routes (pages).

For a better understanding, please read this - [PROTECTING ROUTES USING GUARDS IN ANGULAR](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/18/guards-in-angular-2.html)